# The number of elements $z \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ with $|z|_1 = n$

Tags: linear-algebra, combinatorics, number-theory

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of integers. For $z = ( z_1, \ldots, z_k ) \in \mathbb{Z}^k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $|z|_1 := |z_1| + \ldots + |z_k|$ denote the $l_1$-norm of $z$. Define a function
$$
f : \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, \quad \mathbb{N_0} \ni n \mapsto f(n) := \#\{z \in \mathbb{Z}^k : |z|_1 = n\}, 
$$
i.e., for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $f(n)$ is the number of those $z \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ with $l_1$-norm equal to $n$.

> I am interested in an explicit representation of $f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$.

The problem of finding the number of $z \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ with **non-negative** components such that $|z|_1 = n$ can be identified with the problem of finding the number of $k$-tuples of non-negative integers whose sum is equal to $n$; in other words, we need to find the number of possible ways for placing $n$ objects into $k$ bins, with the possibility of having empty bins. The latter problem can be solved through the [stars and bars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_(combinatorics)) method, and the answer is
$$
\binom{n+k-1}{k-1}.
$$
Indeed,

> observe that any arrangement of stars and bars consists of a total of
> $n + k − 1$ objects, $n$ of which are stars and $k − 1$ of which are
> bars. Thus, we only need to choose $k − 1$ of the $n + k − 1$
> positions to be bars (or, equivalently, choose $n$ of the positions to
> be stars).

In view of the problem posed above, we can further observe that every $k$-tuple of non-negative integers can be modified in
$$
2^{(\text{number of strictly positive integers in the current} \ k \text{-tuple})}
$$
ways to account for the possible negative entries that keep the $l_1$-norm unchanged; namely, we may either alter the sign of the strictly positive entry or leave it as it is. Can this be used to determine the values of the function $f$? Is there perhaps an easier approach?

Comment: you could sum over the number of zeros

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this: ($i$ = number of variables different from $0$)
$$
\sum_{i=0}^{k} 2^i{k \choose i}{n-1 \choose i-1},
$$
where the first binomial represents the number of different ways of assigning zeros in a $k$-tuple, and the second the number of ways in which the rest sums to $n$ via the stars and bars theorem, but with all variables strictly greater than $0$. The $2^i$ accounts for the signs of the non-zero variables.

Otherwise, there is no simpler solution, to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: After looking at this again, it seems to me that the summation should start from $1$, since for every $n \in \mathbb{N}$, we need at least one non-zero variable. The case for $n=0$ should also be considered separately.

Comment: I remember that the binomial generalises by setting ${n \choose -a} = 0$ for all $n \geq 0, a > 0$, and ${n \choose n} = 1$ for all $n\in \mathbb{Z}$, but I can't find a reference for that now. 
If you don't accept the above definition, the formula can be changed by treating the case $i=0$ separately. But I'll argue that, since ${n-1 \choose i-1}$ represents the number of assignments of values for $i$ strictly positive variables which sum to $n$, if the number of variables is 0, we have only one sum - an empty sum - which evaluates to zero, thus one solution if $n=0$, and none otherwise.