# Convergence of a series constructed from the elements of $\mathbb{Z}^k$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $\mathbb{Z}$ be the set of integers. For $z = (z_1, \ldots, z_k) \in \mathbb{Z}^k$, $k \in \mathbb{N}$, let $|z|_1 := |z_1| + \ldots + |z_k|$ denote the $l_1$-norm of $z$.

> Is it true that
> $$
> \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^k} \frac{1}{2^{|z|_1}} < \infty,
> $$
> and, if not, does there exist some $\alpha >0$ (possibly depending on $k$) such that
> $$
> \sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^k} \frac{1}{2^{\alpha|z|_1}} < \infty.
> $$

When $k = 1$, then
$$
\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}} \frac{1}{2^{|z|}} = 1 + 2 \sum_{i=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{2^i} = 1+2=3.
$$
In general, for every $k \in \mathbb{N}$, we can define a function
$$
f_k : \mathbb{N}_0 \rightarrow \mathbb{N}, \quad \mathbb{N_0} \ni n \mapsto f_k(n) := \#\{z \in \mathbb{Z}^k : |z|_1 = n\}, 
$$
i.e., for every $n \in \mathbb{N}_0$, $f_k(n)$ is the number of those $z \in \mathbb{Z}^k$ with $l_1$-norm equal to $n$. As shown in [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4386859/the-number-of-elements-z-in-mathbbzk-with-z-1-n),
$$
f_k(0) = 1, \quad f_k(n) = \sum_{i=1}^{k} 2^i{k \choose i}{n-1 \choose i-1}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N}.
$$
Then
$$
\sum_{z \in \mathbb{Z}^k} \frac{1}{2^{|z|_1}} = \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} f_k(n) \frac{1}{2^n}.
$$
Can this representation be used to come up with an answer? Is there maybe a simpler way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** Your final summation is not correct. For each $n\ge 0$, there are $f_k(n)$ copies of $2^{-n}$ in the summation, so the summation should be
$$
\sum_{n=0}^\infty f_k(n)\frac1{2^n}.
$$
You can probably use your exact expression for $f_k(n)$ to evaluate this summation, but you do not need to be this precise. In order to prove this sum converges, it suffices to find an appropriate upper bound for $f_k(n)$. You can find a simple-to-prove upper bound for $f_k(n)$ which is polynomial in $n$, which suffices to prove convergence since the $(1/2)^n$ factor will dominate any polynomial.

As a further hint for this upper bound, note that all of the lattice points with an $L_1$ norm of $n$ will be inside a certain cube.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Indeed, there was a typo in the post. The way I see it, $f_k(n)$ cannot exceed the number of elements in the set $([-n, n] \cap \mathbb{Z})^k$; the number of elements there is given by $(2n+1)^k$. Is this correct?

Comment: @Harry Exactly!